What's a word or phrase for "a problem with multiple solutions"?
Consider the following situations:

A crossword puzzle where multiple word combinations satisfy the clues and fit the grid.


A mathematical problem where there are multiple ways to come to the correct answer (eg. the many ways to calculate pi)


You need to get from point A to point B and could drive, bicycle, take the bus, or walk.


You want something improved in your house and you speak to different professionals. The plumber recommends something with pipes; the carpenter, with wood; the electrician, with wires and circuits, etc.

In these situations, there are multiple ways to ultimately solve the issue, but each might have its advantages and disadvantages.
Is there a word or phrase describing these situations?

Dilemma: a situation in which a difficult choice has to be made between two or more alternatives, especially ones that are equally undesirable. Oxford Reference
